# How to find the n most frequent words in a PDF file on Ubuntu?

Tags: parsing, ubuntu, pdf

I have various research papers (nearly 150) which are PDF files. I have to find the n most frequent words in these files.

These PDF files have figures and mathematical formulas also. I know how to do it for a single text file with only words. I want to write a script which parses all 150 PDF files and then returns list of n most frequent words in these files.

1. I want a method to parse complicated PDF files (with words,figures and formulas)
2. Then I want to write a script which parses all files in the specific location on my PC and return a list of n most frequent words in all the PDF files combined.

Comment: If you have done this for a single PDF file, could you add that code to your question? In general questions that request code without showing any can attract answers that turn out not to meet some unspecified extra criteria, which come out as soon as the help is supplied! However if you add your current work, it makes it much easier for helpers to see the direction you are going in, and to build upon it.

Answer (score 1):

1) parse PDF files with [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/lib/CAM/PDF.pm)
2) use `split()` in perl like (spaces or tabs) this (for each pdf and each lines inside) to get every words :

```
$words{$_}++ for split /\s+/, $line;
```

3) at the end, sort (or iter and test each values) by numerical values of `%words` and get the 1th element